# how to get the value in imagemap after submiting using POST

Tags: javascript, php

This is the code. I just want to get the value of the area in imagemap using php POST but it return null what should I do?

```
   <?php 
        if(isset($_POST["part"]))
        {
             $part=$_POST["part"];
        echo "<script> alert('".$part."') </script>";
        }
        ?>

    <form action="" name="form" method="POST">

    <img name="newmale" class="mapper" src="newmale.png" width="261" height="548" id="newmale" usemap="#m_newmale" alt="" /><map name="m_newmale" id="m_newmale">

    <area   shape="poly" class="noborder icolor00ff00"coords="114,29,122,309" nohref onClick="form.submit();" name="part"  value="Head"title="Head" alt="Head" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `area` tag is not a form field so it does not get submitted when you submit the form.

What you could do, is add an `href` attribute (not sure if that is even necessary...) and use javascript to:

- catch the click event;
- set the value of a hidden form element based on the clicked `area` element (`href` value, `data` attribute, etc.);
- submit the form.

Comment: can you give me a pattern ?